# spark store job progress details in database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark job which will be periodically submitted to do some job for every hour, so now I need to store that job complete status to some database whenever some action(for example filtering and writing is complete) is completed .

What is best way to get job progress(from spark stage) and store its progress, completion or error if any ?

I thought of using Hbase or some other no SQL but for this simple information Hbase or other DB will be overhead, also looks like there is no support of SQLite with spark, so What is the best way to store this information
I need below information to be put it db

1. Current JOB running, its progress, its in/output paths etc
2. Job completion , Pending Failure status  etc

Comment: Spark ui will show you all these details. For a quick and dirty hack, you can poll the page and parse the relevant information. But I'm sure there are java apis to do the same much more cleanly

Comment: okay, after getting info, where to store and how to store , which db would be best for these information ?

Comment: Take a look at Java DB also called Apache Derby

Comment: I could not find a better guide with scala, can you point to one ? will it work when I submit on cluster ?

Comment: any update on some guide ?